# Convert list of vars to a name-var map

Tags: clojure

I'm using Yesql library for Clojure. Its `defqueries` macro returns a list of Vars representing SQL queries. I want to convert that list into a map of query names to Vars, and have come up with a variant below:

```
(def main-queries (defqueries "sql/main.sql"))
(def query-map
  (apply hash-map
         (reduce
           (fn [coll query]
             (conj coll (->> query meta :name keyword) query))
           [] main-queries)))
```

It seems very inelegant and cumbersome for such an easy task. Can you suggest a shorter and more idiomatic version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the name -> var mappings and then use `into`:

```
(def query-map
  (let [pairs (map (fn [v] [(->> v meta :name keyword) v]) main-queries)]
    (into {} pairs)))
```